# Ordenar via função javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Eu tenho está função, em várias partes do meu código, que realiza o filtro do que foi selecionado e conforme foi digitado.

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, filtro;
    input = document.getElementById("busca");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("tablepesquisa");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    filtro = document.getElementById("filtroPesquisa").value;

    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[filtro];
        if (td) {
            if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Porém agora preciso ordenar conforme o filtro.
Por exemplo, se for número, ordenar pelo número, se for descrição, ordenar por descrição, desta forma ele ordena sempre pela forma que é informado via `C#`.
É possível ? Vi algumas for,as mas não consegui adaptar.

Esse é o meu HTML:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModalPesquisa" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Pesquisar</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <select id="filtroPesquisa" class="form-control">
                                <option value="1">Nome</option>
                                <option value="0">Código</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                            <input type="text" id="busca" placeholder="Pesquisa.." onkeyup="myFunction()" class="form-control uppercase" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="table-overflow col-sm-12">
                        <table class="table table-responsive table-hover" id="tablepesquisa">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Código</th>
                                    <th>Nome</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (var item in Model.Fornecedor)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>@item.Codigo</td>
                                        <td>@item.Nome</td>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <a href="#" onclick="fecha();buscaFornecedor(@item.Id);" title="Selecionar"><i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg"></i></a>&nbsp;
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Qual a dúvida? o código que você postou funciona.

Comment: Eu queria ordenar conforme o filtro. A forma q ele ordena, é a forma que eu carrego a `table` inicial.

Comment: Ahhh, ordenar! Veja minha resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Você transforma a HTMLCollection dos <tr>s em um array, ignorando o primeiro tr que é dos haeders, e usa o sort do objeto Array com uma função `compare()` que compara as strings da coluna selecionada no filtro:

```
function ordenar() {
    table = document.getElementById("tablepesquisa");
    trs = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    filtro = document.getElementById("filtroPesquisa").value;

    [].slice.call(trs, 1) // transforma num array a partir do índice 1 (2o. elemento)
    .sort(function(tr1, tr2) { // usa o sort() do array passando como argumento uma função 
        return compare(tr1, tr2, filtro); // que retorna o resultado da chamada a compare() definida abaixo
    }).forEach(function(val, index) {
        // para cada elemento do array ordenado faz o append do tr na tabela
        table.appendChild(val);
    });
}

function compare(tr1, tr2, filtro) {
    col1 = tr1.getElementsByTagName("td")[filtro].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
    col2 = tr2.getElementsByTagName("td")[filtro].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
    return col1.localeCompare(col2);
}
```

Veja funcionando aqui: [https://js.do/*mari*/364247](https://js.do/_mari_/364247)
Clique no header da coluna para ordenar.

Edit: o código no js.do está um pouco diferente do colado aqui, já que antes tinha feito a ordenação baseada no filtro, e lá fiz de acordo com o header clicado.

Comment: Vou testar e te falo, obrigado por enquanto.

Comment: Se a resposta resolveu seu problema, favor [aceitá-la](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).